# Why does adding one more subtree make a cropped output?

Tags: pstricks, ghostscript, pst-tree

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{treemode=R,edge=\ncline}

\def\ABCD{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{C}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\def\BACD{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{C}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\def\CABD{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{B}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\def\DABC{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{B}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\begin{document}
\psTree[thislevelsep=0]{\Tn}
    % commenting one of the following will fix the problem, but why?
    \ABCD
    \BACD
    \CABD
    \DABC
\endpsTree
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does adding one more subtree make a cropped output?

### My batch file

```
rem LatexDviPsPdf.bat

echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" latex -shell-escape "%~1.tex"

if exist "%~1.dvi" dvips -t unknown "%~1.dvi"

if exist "%~1.ps" gswin64c -r10000 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "%~1.pdf" "%~1.ps"

for %%x in (aux dvi log out ps toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do *not* use the `-r10000` option. I can reproduce the problem when using your `gs` call.

Comment: It must be documented in PSTricks manual. :-) It is really confusing to debug.